# How to navigate after submit radio form in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, tic-tac-toe

I try to build Tictactoe game with different size and i create a game menu to choose which board are gonna play. But i got struggle with how to redirect or navigate the start button after choosing the board size using radio form. I only build two board size just to test. Here's my code

**Menu.js:**

```
import React, { Component,useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Game from './Game'
import Game2 from './Game2'


export default function Menu() {
    const [radio, setRadio] = useState();
    // let navigate = useNavigate(); 
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='title'>
                <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        </div>
        <div className='board-options'>
            <div>Choose Board Size: {radio}</div>
            <div className="size-options">
                <form>
                     <label>
                        <input type="radio"
                        name='size'
                        checked={radio === '3x3'}
                        value='3x3'
                        onChange={(e) => {setRadio(e.target.value)}} />
                        <img src="./images/grid-3.png" alt="grid-3" />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio"
                        name='size'
                        checked={radio === '4x4'}
                        value='4x4'
                        onChange={(e) => {setRadio(e.target.value)}} />
                        <img src="./images/grid-4.png" alt="grid-4" />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio"
                        name='size'
                        checked={radio === '5x5'}
                        value='5x5'
                        onChange={(e) => {setRadio(e.target.value)}} />
                        <img src="./images/grid-5.png" alt="grid-5" />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio"
                        name='size'
                        checked={radio === '6x6'}
                        value='6x6'
                        onChange={(e) => {setRadio(e.target.value)}} />
                        <img src="./images/grid-6.png" alt="grid-6" />
                    </label>
                </form>
                    <button type='submit' id='start'>START</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried to use useNavigate from react-router-dom but it caused the Menu function didn't rendered. I expected to use the START button to navigate to the game files that i choose.

Comment: Do you have implemented switch routes on your App?

Comment: no actually i haven't try that but if you refer to <switch> route in react-router-dom they removed it and change to <Routes> on v6. can you elaborate your suggest? Thanks!  @LahEzcen

Answer (score 0):

You should move the button inside the form and the you can navigate when the onSubmit event is triggered. Here is a small example using the code you provided.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [radio, setRadio] = useState();
  // let navigate = useNavigate();

  const _onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("On submit navigate...");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="title">
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="board-options">
        <div>Choose Board Size: {radio}</div>
        <div className="size-options">
          <form onSubmit={_onSubmit}>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="size"
                checked={radio === "3x3"}
                value="3x3"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setRadio(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <img src="./images/grid-3.png" alt="grid-3" />
            </label>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="size"
                checked={radio === "4x4"}
                value="4x4"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setRadio(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <img src="./images/grid-4.png" alt="grid-4" />
            </label>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="size"
                checked={radio === "5x5"}
                value="5x5"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setRadio(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <img src="./images/grid-5.png" alt="grid-5" />
            </label>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="size"
                checked={radio === "6x6"}
                value="6x6"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setRadio(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <img src="./images/grid-6.png" alt="grid-6" />
            </label>

            <button type="submit" id="start">
              START
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Moved the button inside the form and works on the console. But I struggling with how to write the statement in _onSubmit event to get the value of the board that i choose then navigate to the actual file. Would really appreciate if you can elaborate how should do it. @ManuelConstantin